# Stop waiting on queue at Request/Reply after exception

Tags: jms, apache-camel

Here is my route:

```
<camel:endpoint id="media.retrieve.jms.inout.queue" uri="myActiveMQ:queue:RetrieveDocument?concurrentConsumers=5&amp;replyTo=RetrieveDocument&amp;requestTimeout=30000&amp;disableTimeToLive=true"/>
<camel:endpoint id="media.retrieve.jms.error.queue" uri="myActiveMQ:queue:RetrieveDocument" />
<camel:endpoint id="media.retrieve.jms.processed.queue" uri="myActiveMQ:queue:RetrieveDocument" />

<camel:routeContext id="retrieveMedia">
    <camel:route id="INT_DP_016-Media" routePolicyRef="routePolicy">
        <camel:from uri="direct:retrieveDocument" />
        <camel:onException useOriginalMessage="true">
            <camel:exception>java.lang.Exception</camel:exception>
            <camel:handled>
                <camel:constant>false</camel:constant><!-- send exception back -->
            </camel:handled>
            <camel:process ref="errorHandler" />
            <camel:to uri="ref:media.retrieve.jms.error.queue" />
        </camel:onException>
        <camel:wireTap uri="ref:media.retrieve.jms.processed.queue"/>
        <camel:marshal ref="jaxbMedia" />
        <camel:setProperty propertyName="outputBody">
            <camel:simple resultType="java.lang.String">${body}</camel:simple>
        </camel:setProperty>
        <camel:setExchangePattern pattern="InOut"/>
        <camel:to uri="ref:media.retrieve.jms.inout.queue" />
        <camel:transacted />
        <camel:process ref="mediaProcessor" />
    </camel:route>
</camel:routeContext>
```

I receive exception (expected for my case) in my Processor (*mediaProcessor*) and after that should wait 20000 ms for Timeout (since sent Message wasn't received as I understand).

1) Can I immediately stop waiting and just process exception in my *onException* clause?

2) Why my timeout is 20 sec but not 30 sec as I set at Endpoint options?

**UPDATE**: Just want to clarify since it may be not clear where 20 sec timeout is raised. I have *routePolicy* where **org.apache.camel.spi.RoutePolicy.onExchangeDone(Route, Exchange)** method is invoked after 20 sec starting from the moment when my onException handler was processed:

```
 Caused by: org.apache.camel.ExchangeTimedOutException: The OUT message was not received within: 20000 millis due reply message with correlationID: Camel-ID-michael-desktop-45995-1384079313615-1-5 not received. Exchange[Message: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>...
```

Why route is not finished at Exception handler? Why system still think it has some undelivered messages?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was in my route, it has **ExchangePattern=InOut** but after error was happened the message went to ErrorQueue (**ref:media.retrieve.jms.error.queue**) and wait for reply that have never came.
After setting **ExchangePattern=InOnly** for OnException clause (i.e. when message goes on ErrorQueue) I have immediate reaction on error without 20 sec delay, i.e. onException should be:

```
<camel:onException useOriginalMessage="true">
        <camel:exception>java.lang.Exception</camel:exception>
        <camel:handled>
            <camel:constant>false</camel:constant><!-- send exception back -->
        </camel:handled>
        <camel:process ref="errorHandler" />
        <camel:setExchangePattern pattern="InOnly"/><!--HERE IS A FIX-->
        <camel:to uri="ref:media.retrieve.jms.error.queue" />
    </camel:onException>
```